# Removendo funções do hook do Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tenho esse código no meu arquivo `template-homepage.php`

```
<?php
            /**
             * Functions hooked in to homepage action
             *
             * @hooked storefront_homepage_content      - 10
             * @hooked storefront_product_categories    - 20
             * @hooked storefront_recent_products       - 30
             * @hooked storefront_featured_products     - 40
             * @hooked storefront_popular_products      - 50
             * @hooked storefront_on_sale_products      - 60
             * @hooked storefront_best_selling_products - 70
             */
            do_action( 'homepage' );
            ?>
```

Gostaria de remover a função `storefront_product_categories` do hook `homepage`. Para isso eu criei a seguinte função, como explicado na [documentação do WordPress.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

```
  function remove_hook() {
        remove_action( 'homepage', 'storefront_product_categories', 20);
   } 
   add_action( 'homepage', 'remove_hook' 20);
```

Porém a action ainda é carregada normalmente na minha página. Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de remover essa action por meio de códigos.

Comment: Mas ainda aparece na sua homepage ? Ou só é carregado ?

Comment: Ainda aparece..

Comment: Experimenta remover de dentro da função, deixa apenas a linha do remove_action no arquivo functions.php

Comment: Manda o seu functions.php para termos uma noção melhor